# ZMQ PUB SUB LOST TCP CONNECTION ON PUB side

Tags: zeromq

I use zmq PUB-SUB pattern to notice workers come, after running several days, LOST TCP CONNECTION on pub side last night. 
I create ONE PUB on the server and have 230 SUB client. 
among them, 90 SUB clients have a slow receive issue because of high CPU work after receiving pub messages. PUB lost TCP connections for these 90 subs.

pyzmq:17.0.0

python:2.7.5

In my program design, the slow SUB should be normal because of worker handle is slow, and HWM should protect PUB-SUB pattern. any suggestion?

```
[root@localhost apolo]#  netstat -an|grep "127.0.0.1:5000         ESTABLISHED"|wc -l
230
[root@localhost apolo]#  netstat -an|grep "0 127.0.0.1:5000"|wc -l
141
```

PUB code

```
 zmq_publish = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
 zmq_publish.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
```

SUB code

```
zmq_subscripe = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
zmq_subscripe.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000")
```